# Set default plotting values in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to set default parameters for the graphical plotting of functions. However, whenever I assign a vector to `col` I get the error `graphical parameter "col" has the wrong length`.

The code I'm trying:

```
par(col=c("#000", "#ccc"), font.lab=2, col.axis="#404040")
```

Which I hope outputs a bar plot with a colour black and light gray, whose axis labels are in bold and in a dark gray colour.

For instance, the following code (borrowed from lukeA below) produces a grayscale example, not in colour. Nor is the font in bold.

```
par(font.lab=2, fg="#404040", bg="#ffffff") 
# Defining palette plot colours = NOT gray scale
palette(c("paleturquoise3", "palegreen3"))

set.seed(1)

tRegion <- table(Region = sample(1:3, size = 50, replace = TRUE), 
                 Variant = sample(LETTERS[1:2], size = 50, replace = TRUE))

barplot(t(tRegion), main="Distribution of variant and region",
        xlab="Region", legend = rownames(t(tRegion)))
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

No bold font, and no colour.

Comment: Please provide a (1) minimal and (2) reproducible example and (3) explain, what exactly doesn't work as it should.

Comment: My fault: add `col = seq_len(ncol(tRegion))` to `barplot`. Bold font works here (Windows 7).

Comment: @lukeA That works. What does that last part do? I still don't quite understand why you can't add a vecor to `col` when it's in `par`...

Comment: Seems as if you still have to define colors (in this case: `1` and `2`) and R maps it to the palette that you defined as default palette.

Comment: @lukeA Darn it. Sorry to bother you again, but the bold font isn't working. "Region" still isn't in bold.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce this on my computer (Windows 7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
par(font.lab=2, col.axis="#404040") 
palette(c("#000000", "#cccccc"))
barplot(1:2, col = 1:2, names.arg = 1:2, xlab = "1", ylab = "2")
```

**Edit:**

With regards to your comment - works for me:

```
par(font.lab=2, col.axis="#404040") 
palette(c("paleturquoise3", "palegreen3"))
set.seed(1)
tRegion <- table(Region = sample(1:3, size = 50, replace = TRUE), 
                 Variant = sample(LETTERS[1:2], size = 50, replace = TRUE))
barplot(t(tRegion), main="Distribution of variant and region",beside = TRUE,
        col = seq_len(ncol(tRegion)), xlab="Region", legend = rownames(t(tRegion)))
```

Comment: What does that last line do? The `barplot()`  function?

Comment: It plots a barplot, with a colour black and light gray, whose axis labels are in bold and in a dark gray colour.

Comment: I knew that part, but is it necessary for my case? Or is it merely an example? If it isn't an example, I don't understand what those values `1` and `2` are for.

Comment: It's just an example. The part concerning your question is above: _set default parameters for the graphical plotting of functions_. This is how you do it.